# Validate a ID/NAME tokens in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, validation, token

As in HTML 4 specification noted that :

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

How can I validate an ID/NAME token is valid by using PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose a regular expression such as this one could do the trick :

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_:\.-]*
```

For more informations, see the following section of the manual : [**Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible)**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

And to use that, in PHP, you'd have to use the [**`preg_match()`**](http://www.php.net/preg_match) function :

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_:\.-]*/', $id)) {
    // valid
}
```

Comment: Humph, no it won't -- read the question too fast, I suppose :-( Thanks for your comment, I've edited my answer to fix that

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions.
`/^[a-z]+[\w\_\-\:\.]*/i`

Explanation:

```
/             #beginning of regular-expression
[a-z]         #match any lowercase English letter
+             #match previous token one or more times
[\w\_\-\:\.]  #match any word or digit, underscore, hyphen, colon or dot
*             #match previous token zero or more times
/i            #end regular expression with the i modifier, making it case-insensitive
```

With php you can use [preg_match](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get validation.

For more info on regular expressions, check out [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [GSkinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)'s regexp test

Comment: The i modifier makes the expression case insensitive

Comment: Both of the answer are very helpful. Thanks you all so much.